# Regarding LINQ Usage in Large Loops

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I am wondering what is recommended in the following scenario:

I have a large loop that I traverse to get an ID which I then store in a database like so:

```
foreach (var rate in rates)
{
    // get ID from rate name
    Guid Id = dbContext.DifferentEntity
        .Where(x => x.Name == rate.Name).FirstOrDefault();

    // create new object with the newly discovered 
    // ID to insert into the database
    dbContext.YetAnotherEntity.Add(new YetAnotherEntity
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
        DiffId = Id,
    }
}
```

Would it be better/ faster to do this instead (first get all `DifferentEntity` IDs, rather than querying for them separately)?

```
List<DifferentEntity> differentEntities = dbContext.DifferentEntity;

foreach (var rate in rates)
{
    // get ID from rate name
    Guid Id = differentEntities
        .Where(x => x.Name == rate.Name).FirstOrDefault();

    // create new object with the newly discovered 
    // ID to insert into the database
    dbContext.YetAnotherEntity.Add(new YetAnotherEntity
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
        DiffId = Id,
    }
}
```

Is the difference negligible or is this something I should consider?  Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Why are you asking us.  Try both and find out for yourself.  [Race them horses](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: I think both the code are the same.

Comment: Having said that, doing a DB query is generally one of the least performing single operations you'll have in any application.  Doing one in every single iteration of a very large loop is obviously a very, very bad idea.  You should virtually always strive to avoid doing that.

Comment: @KingKing They sure as heck aren't.  One is doing a DB query in each iteration of a loop; another is searching an in memory list in each iteration of a loop.  Neither is a [proper solution to the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18255410/1159478), but there is still a significant difference between the two.

Comment: @Servy I'm not really experienced in LINQ to entity, but if the `dbContext.DifferentEntity` is deferred, both the code should be the same.

Comment: @KingKing He specifically stated the type as a `List<DifferentEntity>`.  Given the comment above the code as stating that he's fetching the entire list into memory, clearly his intention is pulling the whole list into an in memory list.  If the code failed to do that, the question with respect to his intention, remains.

Comment: @Servy I see now, overlooked that.

Comment: Are you rate names unique?

Comment: @dotNET No, there could be many items of the same name.

Comment: In such situations, does it matter if you get the ID of one row or another?

Comment: @dotNET Probably not, as long as they are they point to the same ID.

Answer (score 2):

Store your Rate Names in a sorted string array (`string[]`) instead of a `List` or `Collection`. Then use `Array.BinarySearch()` to make your search much faster. Rest of what I was going to write has already been written by @Felipe above.

Comment: The solution by Felipe will result in a database `IN` clause, and as such the searching won't be performed in memory in the application.  Databases are designed to make such searching *very* efficient, especially if the relevant columns are indexed.

Comment: mmm... really? he's doing .Select().ToList(), which should materialize his entity query to an in-memory object.

Comment: The rates were *already* an in memory object.  As far as we know, they never came from the DB.  If you take an in memory list and use the `Contains` method on it on the parameter of an expression lambda within an ORM `Where` it will (generally, depending on the provider) map it to a SQL IN caluse, in which the items in the list are all of the values in the IN, and the lambda's parameter is what is being seasrched for.

Answer (score 1):

Run them horses! There is really a lot we do not know. Is it possible to keep all the entities in memory? How many of them are duplicates with respect to `Name`?

A simplistic solution with one fetch from the database and usage of parallelism:

```
// Fetch entities
var entitiesDict = dbContext.DifferentEntity
     .Distinct(EqualityComparerForNameProperty).ToDictionary(e => e.Name); 

// Create the new ones real quick and divide into groups of 500 
// (cause that horse wins in my environment with complex entities, 
// maybe 5 000 or 50 000 fits your scenario better since they are not that complex?)
var newEnts = rates.AsParallel().Select((rate, index) => {
  new {
        Value = new YetAnotherEntity
           { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), DiffId = entitiesDict[rate.Name],},
        Index = index
     }
  })
.GroupAdjacent(anon => anon.Index / 500) // integer division, and note GroupAdjacent! (not GroupBy)
.Select(group => group.Select(anon => anon.Value)); // do the select so we get the ienumerables

// Now we have to add them to the database
Parallel.ForEach(groupedEnts, ents => {
   using (var db = new DBCONTEXT()) // your dbcontext
   {
     foreach(var ent in ents)       
       db.YetAnotherEntity.Add(ent);

     db.SaveChanges();
   }
});
```

In general in database scenarios, the expensive stuff is the fetch and commits, so try to keep them to a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

You can decrease the number of queries you are doing in database. For example, take all names and query findind Ids where the names contains.

Try something like this.

```
// get all names you have in rates list...
var rateNames = rates.Select(x => x.Name).ToList();

// query all Ids you need where contains on the namesList... 1 query, 1 column (Id, I imagine)
var Ids = dbContext.DifferentEntity.Where(x => rateNames.Contains(x.Name).Select(x => x.Id).ToList();

// loop in Ids result, and add one by one
foreach(var id in Ids)
    dbContext.YetAnotherEntity.Add(new YetAnotherEntity
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
        DiffId = id,
    }
```

Comment: He has stated that the loop is a large one.  Since `rates` is large it's unlikely that it will be able to perform this operation as the SQL `IN` clause is generally limited to just a few thousand items.  Assuming he has exceeded that, he'd need to put all of the rates into a temp DB table and then do a `JOIN` in order to perform the operation entirely in the DB.

Comment: It may be worth using something like Ix-Main's `Buffer()` to limit the size of the `IN` clause.